# Detecting touch inside bounding box (alpha mask) of Sprite using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, bounding-box

I am starting to learn Swift2 to develop on iOS using SpriteKit and I cannot seem to detect if I touched a visible part of my Sprite.

I can find which node was touched like this:

```
let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
```

But this detect the touch on the sprite. I would like to detect the touch on the "not transparent" part of the sprite only.

I tried creating a PhysicsBody with an alpha mask bounding box and testing if the bounding box of the node I selected contains the location of the touch like this:

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(texture: sprite.texture!, size: sprite.size)
sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
if (touchedNode.containsPoint(location)){
```

But it didn't help. If I click in a transparent part of my sprite, the event still triggers.

The documentation says "A new physics body is created that includes all of the texels in the texture that have a nonzero alpha value.", so shouldn't it work?

Thanks for your time.

PS: I also tried to be more generous on my alpha threshold, but this also did not work (in case my transparency wasn't perfect).

---

UPDATE:

To add a little more details, I am building a level editor. This means that I will create many nodes, depending on what the user chooses, and I need to be able to select/move/rotate/etc those nodes. I am actually using SKSpriteNodes as  my PNG pictures are automatically added in xcassette that way. I decided to use the PhysicsBody's Alpha Mask bounding box, as this value is shown in the Scene Editor (Xcode) when you select a node, and when selected, the Alpha Mask highlights exactly the part of my Sprite that I want to be able to detect a touch inside.

If I am using the wrong ideas/techniques, please tell me. This is possible as I am only starting to use Swift and SpriteKit.

---

UPDATE 2

I queried the physicsWord (as recommended) to get the right physicsBody and got the name of the attached node like this:

```
let body = self.physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(location)
print(body?.node?.name)
```

But this is still printing the name of the node even if I touch outside the bounding box, which makes no sense to me.

Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Have you found a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `SKPhysicsBody` doesn't define the bounds of the `SKNode`. You can do the hit check by querying the `SKPhysicsWorld` of your scene by calling `bodyAtPoint` on it. That will return the `SKPhysicsBody` you are interested in.

Comment: It seems to me this would be avoiding the elephant in the room. Am I doing it the wrong way? What's the good practice to detect touch on objets of the scene, from their bounding box (alpha mask)? I mean, that solution is clearly a hack around a more fundamental problem that I have, is it not? Thank you anyway for your patience.

Comment: My edited answer is better and seems to be the "right" way to detect touches on SKSpriteNodes

Comment: Hum, I tried doing "self.physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(location)" and this returns my sprite exactly the same way, not caring about the bounding box, even if my bounding box is correct (I can test it by moving the objet, it collides correctly with other objets using the alpha masked bounding box I am trying to detect touch on).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  You actually can't perform the touch on the alpha mask of a Sprite Node and it says it right in the Apple documentation.  You have to use a Composite Box.  I used a shape Node and changed the "line width" to 0 so essentially the composite box is invisible.  Make sure that the Z axis is higher for the composite box and then run the touch event through the composite box shape node instead of the original node.